# Inherited margins displaying incorrectly in Firefox

Tags: css, margin

Pretty simple problem, but am having trouble finding the answer.

Not sure what is happening, but I am getting some kinda of spacing above my header/nav when I apply the rule #content {margin: 10px 0 10px 0}

Am I being a total numpty today? Please help.

"Link removed"

*Edited my 2nd act of numptiness today*

Comment: We can't see that page because the link refers to a page on your intranet. Besides that, the CSS is invalid because it is missing the word "margin". It should read `#content {margin: 10px 0 10px 0;}`. I'm not sure about the "numpty today" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>I cannot see your page so it's a bit of a shot in the dark but</strike> I think you are having a classic case of the "[collapsing margins](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins)".

You should give #container a padding to prevent the margins from collapsing.

```
#container {
 padding: 1px; /* padding prevents collapsing margins of #content */
}
```